# Using LESS in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, less

I'm attempting to use LESS in a tab created via a Chrome extension (chrome.tabs.create), but I'm getting a cross domain error ("NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"), referring to the LESS JavaScript file. I'm not clear on how to set up the permissions. Adding the LESS JavaScript file to "web_accessible_resources" doesn't seem to help. All other files, such as css and js files load fine. It seems I only receive this error from within the less source. Any ideas?

To explain my setup a bit more, the LESS JavaScript file and .less file are loaded in an HTML file something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="static/css/main.less">
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Whatever... 
</body>
</html>
```

This html file is loaded in background.js like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'mypage.html'})
});
```

The manifest file has permissions for "tabs" and "all urls", and loads background.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you include the client side less.js compiler. See also: http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage. Less.js is a client-side javascript. It seems the less.js loads from an other URL (domain) than your main.less file. This can be fixed by enabeling CORS, see: http://enable-cors.org/. On the domain where home.less has been installed, the server should send an Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header.

less.js loads the less files with a XMLHttpRequests which supports CORS for most modern browsers see http://caniuse.com/#search=cors. More details can be found at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

For development use less.js from local folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for release use any less compiler like lessc.